# Is it possible to save a disk state and after that all installations and other changes to be removed on next restart without a software?

Tags: windows-10, virtual-drive, deep-freeze

My friend is going to open a cybercafe and I was wondering how to remove all the applications/ files and other things people create on computer on restart, some recommended a tool Deep Freezer but  I was wondering if it  is possible without any tool, does windows 10 provide such a feature, I was looking into Virtual Drives I couldn't find quite the answer could they provide such a feature?
Like  I  have disk C and create a copy of it where what people install are saved on the copy and on restart those data are lost?

Comment: DeepFreeze exists for a very good reason. Re-imaging your drive for every new customer is a complete pain in the rear.

Comment: @Tetsujin well it wouldn't have to be for every new customer just on restart remove all changes and  go back to the default one

Comment: Which would necessitate re-imaging the drive.

Comment: @Tetsujin yeah but not for every new customer

Comment: Once a day would still be a total nightmare if you had 20 computers to do. It would take you most of the morning. Just buy DeepFreeze & be done with it. I wouldn't dream of using a computer someone else had just had hands on for the past hour - some people just like to download some really bad things… for fun.

Comment: Even if you had the infra structure and tried to re-image after each use it is likely that the computer would be down for at least 10 minutes.  You can setup PXE booting to make the reimage process less painful but it will probably still take 10 mins per PC.  So deepfreeze is still the better solution.

Comment: okay guys thank you, I just want to ask do you have to install deep freeze on each pc or is it possible to manage other pc from the server pc

Comment: Install on each machine - licensing is per seat. …and make sure each computer is rebooted between customers - that way you get no complaints of "I just used your cafe & now I have a virus!"

Comment: "on next restart without a software?" everything is done with software native or not

Answer (score 0):

It's possible without any tool.

Windows 10 now has the feature of
[Windows Sandbox](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-kernel-internals/windows-sandbox/ba-p/301849):

> Windows Sandbox is a new lightweight desktop environment tailored for safely running applications in isolation

Comment: but the users still can install application directly on the drive

Comment: Only if they have admin permission, but as admin they can also disable the Windows Sandbox. If you let a user login with an admin account, there is nothing you can do to protect yourself, except resetting Windows (and a knowledgeable hacker can even modify if you let him work as admin). In any case, once a hacker gets physical access to a computer, there is no way to block him (except maybe surveillance cameras).